# Nominal and cyclical features encoding should be done before or after feature selection?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, feature-selection, feature-engineering

In a dataset I'm using to learn machine learning I have beside many others, one nominal and two cyclical features like bellow:

- Location: "Orlando", "NewYork", "LosAngeles"...
- Date: "2012-01-25", "2010-08-06", "2016-11-30"...
- WinDir: "N", "S", "NW"...

Currently I'm at the feature engineering step of the pipeline and after that I'm gonna make a feature selection. The idea is using chi-squared or maybe mutual information statistic test for these features because the label is binary.

Here the transformations I would do to the mentioned features:

- Location: OrdinalEncoder() and after that LeaveOneOutEncoder()
- Date: pd.to_datetime() and split these dates in Year, Day, Month new features. After that I would do a cyclical encoding(sin/cos technique) in Day and Month.
- WinDir: Same cyclical encoding as before with date

Well, here is my problem. I believe after these transformations(cyclical and leaveoneout) the features will loose the properties needed for the tests I intend to make. So, I was wondering doing a basic transformation making an OrdinalEncoding in "Location" and "WinDir" first, make the feature selection, and if I decide to keep these features make the cyclic encoding and LeaveOneOutEncoder after.

What do you think about this? Any suggestion?

Don't know if you need but here the code for cyclic encoding

```
class CatCyclicEncoder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def fit(self, X, y=None):
    return self

  def transform(self, X, y=None):
    X_aux = []
    cols = range(X.shape[1])
    for index in cols:
      column = X[:, index]
      max_value = column.max()
      sin_values = [math.sin((2 * math.pi * x) / max_value) for x in list(column)]
      cos_values = [math.cos((2 * math.pi * x) / max_value) for x in list(column)]
      X_aux.append(sin_values)
      X_aux.append(cos_values)
    X_encoded = np.array(X_aux).transpose()
    return X_encoded
```

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the features to train machine learning models, then, you need to apply the feature selection method to the features that will actually be used to train the model.

Thus, if you encode the categorical variables and the cyclical features, and plan to use those to train the model, then, you need to apply the selection after the encoding.

If the features do not fit the criteria for the selection tests after the transformation, then you can use different selection tests. More info on feature selection [here](https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/selection/index.html) and [here](https://www.blog.trainindata.com/categories/#feature-selection).

There is also an open-source package that automatically creates [cyclical features](https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/creation/CyclicalFeatures.htm).